I am working on a google colab - React frontend flask integrated project on text summarization.But on clicking button I get backend URL not set
I have a google colab ipynb code
!pip install flask
!pip install transformers
!pip install pyngrok
!pip install flask-ngrok
!pip install python-dotenv
!pip install flask-cors


import os
import shutil
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS
from transformers import pipeline
from pyngrok import ngrok, conf
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import threading
import time
import subprocess

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Initialize Flask app
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='build/build')
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all origins

# Delete the existing 'build' directory if it exists
build_dir = 'build/build'
if os.path.exists(build_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(build_dir)
    print("Deleted the existing 'build' directory.")

# Unzip the build.zip file
!unzip -o build.zip -d build/

# Set up ngrok with authentication token (if using a paid plan)
ngrok.set_auth_token('2hkd7J7tIDvMWx0hPImWMrQfoIi_7tcxWdqFTNucPfD2p9oSM')

# Function to kill all existing ngrok processes
def kill_existing_ngrok():
    try:
        subprocess.run(['pkill', '-f', 'ngrok'], check=True)
        print("Killed existing ngrok processes.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("No existing ngrok processes found.")

# Kill existing ngrok processes before starting a new one
kill_existing_ngrok()

# Start ngrok tunnel to expose the Flask app on port 8000
ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(8000) 
print(f' * Tunnel URL: {ngrok_tunnel.public_url}')

# Define function to generate TL;DR summary
def generate_tldr(full_text):
    # Take the first 2000 characters as TL;DR summary
    tldr = full_text[:2000]
    return tldr.strip()

# Initialize models
models = {
    "GPT-2": {"type": "text-generation", "model": "gpt2-medium"},
    "T5": {"type": "summarization", "model": "t5-base"},
    "BART": {"type": "summarization", "model": "facebook/bart-large-cnn"},
    "PEGASUS": {"type": "summarization", "model": "google/pegasus-cnn_dailymail"}
}

# Define route for serving the React app
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path != "" and os.path.exists(os.path.join(app.static_folder, path)):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

# Define route for generating summaries
@app.route('/generate_summary', methods=['POST'])
def generate_summary():
    try:
        # Get input text from the request
        text = request.json.get('text', '')[:2000]  # Take first 2000 characters as input

        if not text:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No text provided'}), 400

        # Initialize dictionary to store summaries
        summaries = {}

        # Iterate through each model
        for model_name, model_config in models.items():
            # Initialize pipeline for the model
            pipe = pipeline(model_config["type"], model=model_config["model"])

            # Process input text based on model type
            if model_config["type"] == "text-generation":
                # For text generation models like GPT-2
                pipe_out = pipe(text, max_length=512, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
                generated_text = pipe_out[0]['generated_text']
                tldr = generate_tldr(generated_text)
                summaries[model_name] = {"summary": generated_text, "tldr": tldr}
            else:
                # For summarization models like T5, BART, and PEGASUS
                pipe_out = pipe(text)
                summary_text = pipe_out[0]['summary_text']
                tldr = generate_tldr(summary_text)
                summaries[model_name] = {"summary": summary_text, "tldr": tldr}

        return jsonify(summaries)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

# Add endpoint to serve ngrok URL
@app.route('/ngrok_url', methods=['GET'])
def get_ngrok_url():
    return jsonify({"ngrok_url": ngrok_tunnel.public_url})

# Function to run Flask app without debug mode
def run_flask():
    app.run(port=8000)

# Run Flask app in a separate thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=run_flask)
thread.start()

And here is the react frontend App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [summaries, setSummaries] = useState(null);
  const [backendUrl, setBackendUrl] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNgrokUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/ngrok_url'); // Assuming the React app and Flask are served from the same origin
        setBackendUrl(response.data.ngrok_url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching ngrok URL:', error);
        setError('Failed to fetch backend URL');
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (!backendUrl) {
      fetchNgrokUrl();
    } else {
      setLoading(false); // If backendUrl is already set, setLoading to false
    }
  }, [backendUrl]); // Only run this effect once on mount or if backendUrl changes

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!backendUrl) {
      console.error('Backend URL not set');
      setError('Backend URL not set');
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${backendUrl}/generate_summary`, { text: inputText });
      setSummaries(response.data);
      setError(null); // Clear any previous errors
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching summaries:', error);
      setError('Failed to fetch summaries');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Text Summarization</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <textarea
            value={inputText}
            onChange={(e) => setInputText(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter text to summarize..."
            rows="10"
            cols="50"
          />
          <button type="submit" disabled={loading}>Summarize</button>
        </form>
        {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        {summaries && (
          <div className="summaries">
            {Object.keys(summaries).map((model) => (
              <div className="summary" key={model}>
                <h2>{`${model} Summary`}</h2>
                <p>{summaries[model].summary}</p>
                <h3>TL;DR:</h3>
                <p>{summaries[model].tldr}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Now when I click on frontend summarize button, I get backend url not set .Why is this happening and how to solve it.
I wanted to see the summary of a long text I give as input produced by 4 different models.But nothing happened and this error came in the inspect console of web.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

frankly, I don't understand why you do it in Google Colab. Why not run it as normal program on local computer.
